# Adobe AIR StageWebView fail to show web page with javascript

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to write a mobile app using Adobe AIR which shows a web page.
I just want to show the web page and allow the user to browse it.

The problem is when I try to do it I'm getting lots of Javascript errors and the page is partially rendered but in an unreadable way.

I've tried to pass `true` to the `useNative` ctor parameter but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Is there a way to display HTML content from the web in Adobe AIR without using ANE?

Comment: You'll have to give a little more information.  What kind of Javascript errors do you get?  Do you get those errors in the console when you try it in Chrome?    Can you share the address you're trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an ANE to allow users to browse a web page with Adobe AIR. Using a `webView` is the best, simple, popular way.

```
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
webView.loadURL("http://www.example.com");
```

Your problem is not the ActionScript code you developed. It's the page that your are loading into your `webView` element. If the page has Javascript errors with your `webView`, it probably has Javascript errors using a simple browser on your mobile device (or even on a desktop). Thus, passing `True` to `useNative` will not solve your problem.

To solve this problem, run the app in debug mode and look for the Javascript errors in the debug console. For me, for example, the Javascript command `console.log` function was unrecognized by the `webView` and broke many parts of my Javascript execution in my pages. Go through each of the Javascript errors appearing and fix them, until your page runs smoothly.

Comment: On both desktop and mobile browser the site works fine. I'll try to post the code I use.

Comment: I have a same problem, where the same  javascript code is working in old version Air SDK and in latest version it is haveing many syntax error. Please share any resolution if any?